# Scrapy and Python. NameError

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the current currency exchange rates. Please could you take a look and see if you spot an error.

**items.py**

```
import scrapy

class CurrItem(scrapy.Item):
   country = scrapy.Field()
   currency = scrapy.Field()
   value = scrapy.Field()
```

**currencySpider.py**

```
import scrapy

from currency.items import CurrItem

class currencySpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = 'curr'
   allowed_domains = ['https://www.travelex.co.uk/']
   start_urls = [
       'https://www.travelex.co.uk/currency/exchange-rates',
   ]

   def parse(self, response):
       for site in response.xpath('//*[@id="rows"]/div[@class="currency-holder"]'):
        item = CurrItem()
        item['country'] = site.xpath('//*div/span[1]/text()').extract()
        item['currency'] = site.xpath('//*div[1]/div/span[2]').extract()
        item['value'] = site.xpath('//*div[1]/div/span[3]').extract()
        yield item
```

**pipelines.py**

```
import pymongo

from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy import log

class CurrencyPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
       connection = pymongo.MongoClient(
          settings['MONGODB_SERVER'],
          settings['MONGODB_PORT']
        )
        db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
        self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
      valid = True
      for data in item:
          if not data:
            valid = False
            raise DropItem("Missing {0}!".format(data))
      if valid:
        self.collection.insert(dict(item))
        log.msg("currency was added to MongoDB database!",
                level=log.DEBUG, spider=spider)
      return item
```

**settings.py**

```
BOT_NAME = 'currency'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['currency.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'currency.spiders'

ITEM_PIPELINES = ['currency.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline', ]

MONGODB_SERVER = "localhost"
MONGODB_PORT = 27017
MONGODB_DB = "ProTech"
MONGODB_COLLECTION = "currency"
```

**Command prompt output:**

```
C:\Users\MyName\currency>scrapy crawl curr
2015-09-27 20:18:02 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: currency)
2015-09-27 20:18:02 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-09-27 20:18:02 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'cu
rrency.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['currency.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'currency'}

2015-09-27 20:18:02 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsol
e, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-09-27 20:18:03 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddl
eware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultH
eadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMidd
leware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-09-27 20:18:03 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddlewa
re, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-09-27 20:18:03 [py.warnings] WARNING: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\
pipelines\__init__.py:21: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: ITEM_PIPELINES defined as a
list or a set is deprecated, switch to a dict
  category=ScrapyDeprecationWarning, stacklevel=1)

2015-09-27 20:18:03 [py.warnings] WARNING: C:\Users\MyName\currency\currency\p
ipelines.py:5: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.log` has been deprecated
, Scrapy now relies on the builtin Python library for logging. Read the updated
logging entry in the documentation to learn more.
  from scrapy import log

Unhandled error in Deferred:
2015-09-27 20:18:03 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_comm
and
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 57, in run

    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 153, in crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1274, in
unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1128, in
_inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 71, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 83, in _create_en
gine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 67, in __init
__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\scraper.py", line 70, in __ini
t__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 56, in from_cr
awler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 32, in from_se
ttings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 49, in load_ob
ject
    raise NameError("Module '%s' doesn't define any object named '%s'" % (module
, name))
exceptions.NameError: Module 'currency.pipelines' doesn't define any object name
d 'MongoDBPipeline'
2015-09-27 20:18:03 [twisted] CRITICAL:
```

Answer (score 4):

You should place the right pipline class name here:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['currency.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline', ]
```

change it to:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['currency.pipelines.CurrencyPipeline', ]
```

Answer (score 3):

So, from the error:

```
exceptions.NameError: Module 'currency.pipelines' doesn't define any object named 'MongoDBPipeline'
```

It looks like `scrapy` needs some help actually articulating with Mongo. You can see that in your config file you have the following line:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['currency.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline', ]
```

It appears that you don't actually have that item pipeline defined. Based on what you have above, renaming `CurrencyPipeline` as `MongoDBPipeline` should fix your problem.

Also, though this won't break your program, you shouldn't be using `scrapy.log`. `Python` has some excellent builtin logging functionality with documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html). If it's been deprecated I wouldn't advise using it.

Comment: That took away my errors which is great, but its still not saving it to Mongo. Is my Xpaths right atleast? or could it be something else?

Comment: @Jaco your `process_item` code seems misguided. What are you trying to do? It should really just be `self.collection.insert(item)`, not sure what any of the other code is supposed to be doing, but it's not. Also where is `CurrItem` defined?

Comment: Im new to pyhton and scrapy and i worked through a tutorial and it worked with the pipelines.py code so i reused it.

Comment: Also, the CurrItem is only used in the items.py and currencySpider.py