# Scrapy NameError with Item Pipeline when calling from different file

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

In short I have my "scraper_control.py" that holds the code to run the different spiders and has a pipeline within it:

```
#scraper_control.py
spiders = {"test_quotes": ToScrapeCSSSpider}
items = []

class ItemCollectorPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        items.append(item)

crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(
    {
        "USER_AGENT": "scrapy",
        "LOG_LEVEL": "INFO",
        "ITEM_PIPELINES": {"__main__.ItemCollectorPipeline": 100},
    }
)

def runspider(spider):
    crawler_process.crawl(spiders[spider])
    crawler_process.start()
    return items
```

Trying to run this from a separate file looks like this (we will call it "testing.py"):

```
#testing.py
import scraper_control
import json

def runScraper(spider):
    sc= scraper_control
    scraper_results = sc.runspider(spider)
    json_result = json.dumps(scraper_results)
    print(json_result)

runScraper("test_quotes")
```

Note the messiness with the results was just some playing around. I receive the following error when I run the testing.py file:

```
builtins.NameError: Module '__main__' doesn't define any object named 'ItemCollectorPipeline'
```

If I just run the scraper by adding a line to scraper_control.py, it runs fine. Any clue what I need to change here?

Comment: have you checked this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811308/scrapy-and-python-nameerror

Comment: @manzt I did however that question is concerned with the pipeline and settings in entire different files rather than all in one.

Comment: `__main__` works only if you have all code in one file and you runs this single file. When you import to other file then other file see all as `scraper_control.`

Comment: instead of `sc = scraper_control` you could do `import scraper_control as sc`

Comment: @furas Thanks for your comment, I was able to get it to work with the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

This was a lot more straightforward than I thought. All I had to do was change

```
"ITEM_PIPELINES": {"__main__.ItemCollectorPipeline": 100},
```

to

```
"ITEM_PIPELINES": {"scraper_control.ItemCollectorPipeline": 100},
```

Effectively just pointing it at the file it's in and it worked as intended.